# Can I implement my own authentication process in force.com or it is against terms of service?

Tags: salesforce, force.com

I am just wondering if it is permited to implement my own authentication process in force.com or it is against terms of service or any rules. Link to official documentation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create an authentication for a site : [look here](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Authenticating_Users_on_Force.com_Sites).

If you want authenticated users in your site basically you need a licence for each authenticated user, i believe that it's not permitted to create your own authentication, in the link i gave you it's said : "please don't be tempted to build your own authentication process".

If your authenticated users already have their licences, you can customize the authentication process easily, there's the Site class for that [look here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_sites.htm)

Hope this help :)